# Using GamerServices in Wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I thought about using the Leaderboard from XNA GamerServices in my (XAML) WP8 game, because there is a capability (ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES) and in the description of XNA, they tell, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices is still supported.

But I have no clue how to achieve this in WP8. There are docs for doing this in Xbox and WP7, but this doesn't work, since I don't have the Game Components.

I actually want to use the default users gamertag (so he don't need to log in) and a leaderboard to display highscores. If this is not possible, are there any better (and very easy) solutions?